# Looping Audio with AudioToolbox.framework

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox

I have would like to play audio on the startup of my app, but, first of all, the audio doesn't play! No matter how i code it. And secondly I would love to loop it if i can.

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ScaryMusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile1], &soundID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    NSLog(@"Sound Played");

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

AVAudioPlayer *player;
NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ScaryMusic" withExtension:@"mp3"];
if (soundFileURL != nil)
{
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite
}

[player play];
```

This is better for mp3's and such. SystemSound is mostly reserved for short .wav type sounds.

Comment: Thank you! :D But can i play several sounds at the same time with this function? It doesn't seem to be letting me.. :/

Comment: Yes you can but you need a new player for each sound.
This answer should help for multiple sounds
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11195226/1550927

Comment: If this worked for you accept the answer so others can see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the docs you'll find that mp3 is not among the formats supported by AudioToolbox