# Play sound repeatedly when tapping a button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to add sound to my app. I would like it for when I tap a button, it plays a quick sound. However, when the button is tapped quickly and repeatedly, the sound does not work as well (It only plays 1 or 2 times when I tap the button 5 or 6 times). Here is my code in the button

```
player.play()
```

I have this outside

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()
let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("illuminati", ofType: "wav")
```

Viewdidload:

```
do {
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
    } catch {}
```

How can I play the sound repeatedly better? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `play` multiple time before the previous call finished. You need to keep track of how many times the user click the button and the play song one by one.

This is what you can do:

1. Use an integer in you class to keep track of number of times that the button is clicked

   ```
   var numClicks = 0
   var buttonClickTime:NSDate? = nil // The last time when the button is clicked

   @IBAction func yourbuttonclickfunction() {
       numClicks++; 
       buttonClickTime = NSDate()
       player.play()
   }
   ```
2. Register the delegate of `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`

   ```
   do {
         try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))

         // Add this 
         player.delegate = self
   } catch {}
   ```
3. In the delegate function, play the song again when the previous one reach the end:

   ```
   optional func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,
                        successfully flag: Bool)
   {
        if --numClicks > 0
        {
            let now = NSDate()
            let duration = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(buttonClickTime!)

            // If the button click was less than 0.5 seconds before
            if duration < 0.5 
            {
                // Play the song again
                player.play();
            } 
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: So the code works fine. However, when I tap the button repeatedly, it plays the sound that many times. If is stop tapping, the sound keeps playing. How  can I fix this? Putting a 'player.stop()' before 'player.play()' does not seem to work...

Comment: @penatheboss, Hello. I am actually a bit confused. You want to player to hear the sound play the number of times as the number of times he tap on the button. Isn't that what you want? If you stop the playing when the user is not not tapping on the button, then you won't get the player to play the number of times you are expecting.

Comment: Have you ever played the game cookie clicker? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cookie-clickers/id703439482?mt=8

Comment: I want It to be someting Like this

Comment: @penatheboss, so the idea is to stop the playing if the user stops clicking for 0.5 seconds. Please refer to my modification of the answers. It seems this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Yuchen Zhong. It works nicer. The sound does not play for too long. However, if I tap the button 10 times, it only plays the sound 2 or 3 times. Do you know if there is a way to play multiple sounds at the same time?

Comment: @penatheboss, maybe if you want allow them to overlap each other, you only simply need to create multiple `AVAudioPlayer` objects (one for each button click event). Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried using the code I usually do (declaring the audiopath and the player, and then setting up the player, then playing the player). However, it is not working. I put the code in the button. Do you know why?

Comment: @penatheboss, please also take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194838/avaudioplayer-help-playing-multiple-sounds-simultaneously-stopping-them-all-at Is that what you are doing? It should work.

Comment: Thanks @YuchenZhong  I will try the code when I get a chance

Answer (score 2):

The reason your sound only plays a few time is because the song plays until finished or until you stop it, even if you press the button multiple times in succession.
You could just stop the music manually, so before you press a button that plays a sound you say

```
player.stop()
```

and than

```
player.play()
```

Is that helping?